# If $|f|>0$ in some nonzero measure set can I necessarily find a nonzero measure subset where $|f|>\epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given that there exists a measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and a measurable subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ with nonzero measure such that $|f|>0$ in $A$. Is it true that there exists a nonzero measure subset $B\subset A$ with nonzero measure such that $|f|>\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$

I'm not quite sure how to start with this. I suspect this is true because if there is no such set $B$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{x\in A:|f(x)|>\epsilon\}$ has zero measure, but I'm not sure how to conclude that this is a contradiction as $\epsilon\downarrow 0$

Comment: *Hint.* $\{|f|>0\}=\bigcup_{\epsilon\in\mathbb Q_+^*}\{|f|>\epsilon\}$. Use $\sigma$-additivity.